# Method undefined in Java

Tags: java, methods, undefined

I am working on a Java project with multiple classes. One class has the main method, one class is a max heap data structure, and the third is a wrapper class for the object to be stored in the max heap.

In the wrapper class, I define the following method:

```
public void setHeapLoc(int l)
    {
        heapLoc = l;
    }
```

In the max heap class, I have the following code:

```
public int insert(CompEq comp) {
  assert s < size : "No room";
  int current = size++;
  Heap[current] = comp;             
  while ((current != 0)  && (Heap[current].compareTo(Heap[parent(current)]) > 0)) {
    swap(Heap, current, parent(current));
    current = parent(current);
  }
  Heap[current].setHeapLoc(current); //<-------This line is the problem
  return curr;
}
```

On the line I pointed out in the above method, I get the error "The method setHeapLoc(int) is undefined for the type CompEq"

Meanwhile, in the main method, if I say:

```
CompEq temp = new CompEq(eq);
temp.setHeapLoc(1);
```

It works perfectly.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

EDIT: Casting does not help. Changing it to

```
Heap[current].setHeapLoc(current);
```

ADDS an error "Unnecessary cast from CompEq to CompEq."

Comment: Post declaration and initialization of Heap Variable and also HeapEq class definition?

Comment: Also since you mentioned that casting isn't helping post the part where you do cast as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is `CompEq` a subclass of `Heap` and `setHeapLoc` is defined in `CompEq`?

In that case, you would need to cast it before you can call the function. I hope you realize this is probably an indication of bad design somewhere

```
((CompEq)Heap[current]).setHeapLoc(current)
```

Comment: No, CompEq is it's own class. Heap stores objects of type CompEq. setHeapLoc is defined in CompEq.

I have tried casting, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @elykl33t Can you show us the definition of the `CompEq` class. The upper case in `Heap` threw me, typically upper case is used for types

Answer (score 0):

As the method setHeapLoc is undefined for the Heap Type  Following will result in compilation error.therefore,this assignment is allowed as Heap is a superclass of CompEq. In order to use a reference of a class type to invoke a method, the method must be defined at or above that class in the class hierarchy. Hence an object of Class Heap cannot invoke a method present in Class CompEq, since the method CompEqMethod is not present in Class Heap or any of its superclasses. Hence this problem can be colved by a simple downcast by casting the Heap object reference to the CompEq Class Object reference as done in the program.

((CompEq) Heap[current]).setHeapLoc(current);